# Punctuation and return (statements?) in text field?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

This is really difficult to describe as I don't know what the proper term is here, but I have written a simple `self.textfield.text=@"text"` line, but **

> how can I use punctuation like double-quotes `(")` without Xcode
>   thinking its actual code rather than text

** (I think I have an idea but I don't know the syntax).

And **

> is it also possible to add returns or enters when setting text like
>   this?

I am a Java programmer and can do this in that language, but I'm new to app development!
Any Demo/Example will be very much helpful for me.

** Thanks for the help,

Comment: self.textfield.text=@"text\""; just escape them.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to add [escape characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C):

```
NSString *string = @"This is a quote: \"To err is human\"";
NSString *string = @"This is a tab:\tTo err is human";
NSString *string = @"This is a newline:\n"To err is human\"";
```

Comment: ...and you can escape newlines with `\n`: `@"This is a \"line\".\nThis is another \"line\"."`